# Meteor, attaching a unique page with a collection with IronRouter

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

Using Meteor's IronRouter, how do I attach a collection's unique ID and create a page based on the said ID?  In addition, in the page, how do I take information from that collection and display it?

In the collection, I have tried to collect the ID of the submission but I'm stumped how to retrieve the data from the collection on the unique page.

So far, for the collection, I have:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Works } from '../api/works.js';

import './work.js';
import './body.html';

Template.main.helpers({
  works() {
    return Works.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
  },
});

Template.main.events({
  'submit .new-work'(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const title = event.target.title.value;
    const workBriefDesc = event.target.workBriefDesc.value;
    const workFullDesc = event.target.workFullDesc.value;
    const workId = this._id;

    Works.insert({
      title,
      workBriefDesc,
      workFullDesc,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      owner: Meteor.userId(),
      username: Meteor.user().username,
      workId,
    });

     event.target.title.value = '';
     event.target.workbriefdesc.value = '';
     event.target.workfulldesc.value = '';

  },
});
```

And for the IronRouter file:

```
Router.route('/works/:_id', function () {
  this.render('Collab');
}, {
  name: 'collab',
    data: function(){
        var workId = this.params._id;
        return Works.findOne({ _id: workId });
    }
});
```

And the template file:

```
<!-- Publishing the template work -->
<template name="main">
                        <form class="new-work col s12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s6">
                                    <input id="title" type="text" class="validate">
                                    <label for="title">Name of work</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-field col s6">
                                    <select>
                                        <option value="" selected>Choose category</option>
                                        <option value="1">Prose</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <label></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input id="workBriefDesc" type="text" length="250">
                                    <label for="workBriefDesc">Brief description</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <textarea id="workFullDesc" class="materialize-textarea" length="10000"></textarea>
                                    <label for="workFullDesc">Full description</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <textarea id="workessay" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                                    <label for="workessay">Essay</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-grey btn-flat center" type="submit" name="action">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
    {{#each works}} {{ > work}} {{/each}}
</template>

<!-- Link to the unique page -->
<template name="work">
    Go to <a href="/work/{{_id}}">work</a>
</template>


<!-- Unique page attached to ID -->
<template name="collab">
    {{title}} <br>
    {{workBriefDesc}} <br>
    {{workFullDesc}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your helper:

```
Template.main.helpers({
  works: function(){
    return Works.findOne({_id:Router.current().params.workId});
  },
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it breaks foreach loop in the main template. In addition, I tried putting it in the IronRouter data function section to test, but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Helper : I think, you should put one conditions on your "works" helper.

**YOUR CODE**

```
Template.main.helpers({
  works() {
    return Works.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
  },
});
```

In above code, please change the return statement and try.

**UPDATE**

```
return Works.findOne({_id:Router.current().params._Id});
```

Hope this work!

Comment: Like with the other solution, it breaks the loop in the main template.